# Add tooltips to the list of translatable strings

Tags: bug, localization, tooltips

It seems that tooltips for "Hide Hot Network Questions" and for "Activity Data" on [the user preferences page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) are not translatable yet:

> [image: HNQ]

> [image: Activity data]

Could this please be fixed.